# Efficient way to add many rows to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, append

I really want to speed up my code.

My already working code loops through a DataFrame and gets the start and end year. Then I add it to the lists. At the end of the loop, I append to the empty DataFrame.

```
rows = range(3560)

#initiate lists and dataframe
start_year = []
end_year = []

for i in rows:

    start_year.append(i)
    end_year.append(i)


df = pd.DataFrame({'Start date':start_year, 'End date':end_year})
```

I get what I expect, but very slowly:

```
    Start date  End date
0   1            1
1   2            2
2   3            3
3   4            4
```

Comment: There is no need to instantiate your df. Also, is the indentation accurate here?

Comment: I don't understand  the `df.append` at all, actually

Comment: Or `rows = range(len(disaster_data))` which means that `rows` is just an integer. I don't think this example resembles your actual code, or, there are serious issues.

Comment: Updated code, according to your critique. Still wondering, how it can be made faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be made faster. The trick is to avoid [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) (or, worse [`pd.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)) in a loop. You *can* use `list(range(3560))`, but you may find [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) even more efficient. Here you can assign an array to multiple series via [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict.fromkeys(['Start date', 'End date'], np.arange(3560)))

print(df.shape)
# (3560, 2)

print(df.head())
#    Start date  End date
# 0           0         0
# 1           1         1
# 2           2         2
# 3           3         3
# 4           4         4
```

Comment: I asked specifically about the indentation in comments  for your first sentiments. Append is not in a loop, apparently.

Comment: @roganjosh, Good point, have amended the explanation slightly. Of course, `list.append` in a loop still isn't particularly efficient.

Comment: Hey @jpp thanks for the answer. I will mark this as solved, but the truth is, I failed to explain my problem. Actually I have real data, not just an arange... I just oversimplified it.